# Recebo mensagens em background mas não mostra o badge com o contador de mensagens

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Em meu App consigo receber mensagens em Background. Em foreground eu consigo visualizar o badge e a qde de mensagens recebidas. Só não consigo em background. Uso o plugin ***Xamarin.FirebasePushNotification*** do **RendyDelRosario**, o qual gostei bastante para receber PN. Conversando com o Rendy via skype ontem, ele me disse isso:

> You cannot use Xamarin Forms code when application is closed so that
>   won't work Xamarin Forms features need the application to be opened in
>   order to work because is initialized. But when closed Xamarin Forms is
>   not initialized because initialization depends on UI You need to
>   update this without the use of any Xamarin Forms dependencies in order
>   for it to work

Bem, alterei o evento de recebimento do **App.xmal.cs** para **MainApplication.cs**, conforme abaixo e mesmo assim ainda continuo recebendo PN e não mostrando o badge:
MainApplication

```
public override void OnCreate()
        {
                base.OnCreate();

                //If debug you should reset the token each time.
#if DEBUG
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);
#else
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, false);
#endif
            try
            {
                //Handle notification when app is closed here
                CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received");
                    Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send<Autorizador.Droid.MainApplication>(this, "PushNotificationRecievedClosed");
                };
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string err = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

MainActivity

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            try
            {
                instance = this;
                TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
                ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

                base.OnCreate(bundle);

                global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

                badge = new Badge(this);

                MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>(this, "PushNotificationRecieved", (sender) => {
                    Contador++;
                    badge.count(Contador);
                });

                MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Autorizador.Droid.MainApplication>(this, "PushNotificationRecievedClosed", (sender) => {
                    Contador++;
                    badge.count(Contador);
                });

                MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>(this, "ResetBadge", (sender) => {
                    Contador = 0;
                    badge.count(Contador);
                });                

                LoadApplication(new App());

                FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(Intent);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string err = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

alguém sabe me dizer porque eu não consigo mostrar o badge quando o app está em background?